# apply function to pandas grouby with some arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 232 categories in the column `'category'`. Also, I have a function which takes a dataframe as input, applies some operations on a column given as argument, and outputs a dataframe with 2 more columns

```
def create_delta_days(df,interval,col):
    ----df['new column 1'] = do some work here----
    ----df['new column 1'] = do some work here----
    return df
```

When I do `df.groupby('category').apply(create_delta_days())`, I get `create_delta_days() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'df', 'interval', and 'col'`

How do I pass arguments to finally get df with 2 more columns for each category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `()` (extra parenthesis):

```
df.groupby('category').apply(lambda x: create_delta_days(x, 7, 'rank'))
```

Comment: but I have to pass the arguments, interval = 7 and col='rank', don't I? where do I enter that information?

Comment: this prints a groupby object with different categories. How do I change my original df ?

Comment: @AmanArora That is something not good with your code, you should ask a new question about that, I solved your current problem.